# Maps load slowly

Tags: android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I completed the necessary steps to enable Maps in my Android app such as getting the API Key using the SHA-1 fingerprint however, the maps load very slowly. In my app I am loading the map with a marker of device location. I understand getting this fix takes a while but in my app, it is taking about 25-30 seconds. Please see the logs below:

```
10-13 08:16:09.717 16078-16078/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-13 08:16:09.767 16078-16085/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
10-13 08:16:09.769 16078-16085/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
10-13 08:16:09.769 16078-16085/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
10-13 08:16:09.870 16078-16078/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.demo.mapinviewpager-1/lib/arm64
10-13 08:16:09.895 16078-16078/? I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.demo.mapinviewpager, real application class is null.
```

And then after about 24 seconds, the map loads with the current location:

```
10-13 08:16:33.034 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.demo.mapinviewpager-1/lib/arm64
10-13 08:16:33.083 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
10-13 08:16:33.382 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-13 08:16:33.880 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager D/PagerAdapter: Creating FragmentA
10-13 08:16:33.922 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager D/PagerAdapter: Creating FragmentB
10-13 08:16:33.933 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager D/PagerAdapter: Creating FragmentC
10-13 08:16:34.007 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/FragmentA: isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS
10-13 08:16:34.007 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/FragmentA: Google API client is null so creating one
10-13 08:16:34.265 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/zzai: Making Creator dynamically
10-13 08:16:34.507 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000004/n/arm64-v8a
10-13 08:16:34.585 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 9452000
10-13 08:16:34.599 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 9683440
10-13 08:16:34.743 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager D/FLASH: Couldn't find file:  /data/user/0/com.demo.mapinviewpager/files/DATA_ServerControlledParametersManager.data.com.demo.mapinviewpager (No such file or directory)
10-13 08:16:35.043 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/FragmentA: In onCreateView, calling getMapAsync()
10-13 08:16:35.059 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager E/MapInPagerDemoActivity: LatLong from FragmentA came up empty
10-13 08:16:35.064 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager E/MapInPagerDemoActivity: LatLong from FragmentA came up empty
10-13 08:16:35.118 16078-17427/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 74df444, I409c65498b
                                                                 Build Date                       : 06/22/16
                                                                 OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.08.00.02
                                                                 Local Branch                     : N16
                                                                 Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                 Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                 Reconstruct Branch               : 
10-13 08:16:35.143 16078-17427/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-13 08:16:35.143 16078-17427/com.demo.mapinviewpager D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
10-13 08:16:35.193 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/Choreographer: Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-13 08:16:35.460 16078-17507/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/b: Sending API token request.
10-13 08:16:35.617 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/FragmentA: In onMapReady, is map loaded yet?
10-13 08:16:35.708 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/FragmentA: In onConnected(), Google API client is:: true
10-13 08:16:35.724 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/MapInPagerDemoActivity: LatLong from FragmentA is: 37.51554646 and long is: -122.26936605
10-13 08:16:35.745 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/FragmentA: ::Google::My current location set::
10-13 08:16:36.234 16078-17507/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/b: Received API Token: <a token number> / Expires in: 432000000ms
10-13 08:16:36.234 16078-17507/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/c: Scheduling next attempt in 431700 seconds.
10-13 08:16:36.243 16078-17507/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/d: Saved auth token
10-13 08:16:36.271 16078-17461/com.demo.mapinviewpager D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
10-13 08:16:37.067 16078-17488/com.demo.mapinviewpager W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
10-13 08:16:37.074 16078-17488/com.demo.mapinviewpager W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
10-13 08:16:37.082 16078-17488/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1
10-13 08:16:37.082 16078-17488/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 1
10-13 08:16:37.129 16078-17488/com.demo.mapinviewpager D/GoogleCertificates: com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates module is loaded
10-13 08:16:37.207 16078-17488/com.demo.mapinviewpager D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 172 Google release certificates
10-13 08:16:37.217 16078-17488/com.demo.mapinviewpager D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 336 Google certificates
10-13 08:16:38.582 16078-16089/com.demo.mapinviewpager W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.827ms
10-13 08:16:40.889 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager D/FragmentA: In onLocationChanged(), sending new lat: 37.5323156 and long: -122.2899224
10-13 08:17:01.934 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/FragmentA: In onConnected(), Google API client is:: true
10-13 08:17:02.011 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/MapInPagerDemoActivity: LatLong from FragmentA is: 37.5323156 and long is: -122.2899224
10-13 08:17:02.013 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager I/FragmentA: ::Google::My current location set::
10-13 08:17:02.114 16078-16078/com.demo.mapinviewpager D/Fragmenta: In onLocationChanged(), sending new lat: 37.5323156 and long: -122.2899224
10-13 08:17:04.182 16078-16085/com.demo.mapinviewpager W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.447ms
```

I am using `Activity` with a `ViewPager` loading three `Fragments`.

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity
                implements FragmentA.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
                    FragmentB.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_in_pager_demo);

        ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setClipToPadding(false);
        pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        // This is required to avoid a black flash when the map is loaded.  The flash is due
        // to the use of a SurfaceView as the underlying view of the map.
        mPager.requestTransparentRegion(mPager);

        //always start w/ Maps View, FragmentA
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
        //do something
    }

    @Override
    public void makeUseOfNewLocation(UserLatLong userLatLong) {
         newUserLatLong = userLatLong;
    }


   /**
    * Used for fetching data from activity
    * @return
    */
    public UserLatLong getLLFromActivity() {
        if(newUserLatLong == null) {
           Log.e(TAG, "LatLong from FragmentA came up empty");
        }
        return newUserLatLong;
    }
}
```

**MyPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentB();
            case 1:
                //map fragment
                return new FragmentA();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentC();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**FragmentA.java** /**does all the map related work*/

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //checks whether play services are installed
    if(!servicesAvailable()) {
        return;
    }

    //Create the location client to start receiving updates
    buildGoogleApiClient();

    if(mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    if (supportMapFragment != null) {
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    // Display the connection status
    try {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( getActivity(), new String[] {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                    TAG_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException: " + se.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        try {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
                final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),
                                                    mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

                //wrap LatLng into UserLatLong
                userLatLong.setLat(latLng.latitude);
                userLatLong.setLng(latLng.longitude);
                //updating the value in the interface
                mLLCallback.makeUseOfNewLocation(userLatLong);

                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20);
                mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
                Log.i(TAG, "::Google::My current location set::");

                mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng1) {
                        mMap.clear(); //removes the previous marker
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1));
                        //TODO: update A/C Fragments with these new coordinates
                        float x = (float) latLng1.latitude;
                        float y = (float) latLng1.longitude;
                        Log.d(TAG, "Map clicked w/ lat: " + x + " and long: " + y);

                        //wrap LatLng into UserLatLong
                        userLatLong.setLat(latLng1.latitude);
                        userLatLong.setLng(latLng1.longitude);

                        //updating the value in the interface
                        mLLCallback.makeUseOfNewLocation(userLatLong);
                    }
                });

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                //for zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(12).build();
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                //TODO: Constrain the camera target to bounds defined by API
                mMap.setMinZoomPreference(Constants.DEFAULT_MIN_ZOOM);
                mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(Constants.DEFAULT_MAX_ZOOM);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Current location was null so, calling startLocationUpdates()",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Begin polling for new location updates
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        } catch (SecurityException se1) {
            Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException1: " + se1.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Google API client is null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    //TODO: throttle these based on the needs
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(Constants.UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(Constants.FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    try {
        //used for foreground use cases
        //for background use a PendingIntent
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( getActivity(), new String[] {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                    TAG_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException see) {
        Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException2: " + see.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: if you mean that the app takes 25 seconds to take a GPS fix (try going outside). Anyway you should load the map, the app and then try to get the fix.
Without your code it's impossible to help you more, the log is not enough since no crash occour

Comment: Thank you. Just curious - how does Google Maps get the fix efficiently even while indoors? I updated my post w/ my Activity, Adapter and Fragment that loads the map.

Comment: it uses FusedLocationProvider . You can use it if you want

Comment: As you can see, I too am using FusedLocationApi.